# How to turn this into a global javascript function effecting all values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, load

This code loads via jQuery a page based onclick events of checkboxes.

```
function product_analysis(address, box) {
    if (box.checked) {
        $('#product_' + box.alt).load(address);
    } else {
        $('#product_' + box.alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html');
    }
    document.getElementById('product_quantity_PRI_' + box.alt).value = box.value;
};
```

With the onclick event looking as follows `onclick="product_analysis('http://www.samedomain.blahblahblah', this)`

What I need is that for all checkboxes that are already ticked on page load to have this function applied to them all. I am reasonably confident with javaScript but when it comes to objects and arrays I get lost.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to find all the checkboxes that are currently checked:

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

If you then want to do something to all of them, you can use the `each` function like this:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {

  // alerts the checkbox for example
  // "this" referes to the checkbox, one after the other
  alert(this); 

})
```

Or to do what you asked for ("for all checkboxes that are already ticked on page load to have this function applied to them all"):

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {

  product_analysis("someaddress", this);

})
```

**EDIT:** To address the second issue (not a part of the original question, but to the comments below):

I will assume that you have fields like this in your markup. Use some meaningful IDs rather than my stupid examples of course.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" id="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" id="baz" />
```

Then you'll put the following in your JS:

```
var addresses = {
   foo: 'some_address',
   bar: 'some_other_address',
   baz: 'yet_another_one'
};

$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
  product_analysis(addresses[this.id], this);
})
```

That will invoke product_analysis with the address that corresponds to the ID of the checkbox.

**EDIT (again):**

There is actually a way to add meta-data directly to the html-tags that I wasn't aware of. You can add attributes prefixed by "data-" to your tag, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-address="someaddress" data-foo="something else" data-bar="more data!" />
```

You can read more about it on [John Resigs blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Comment: All very good and yes I want that function product_analysis applied to all checked however how could you retrieve the "someadress" from the original onclick event for product analysis. So at the moment on each checkbox is an onclick"product_analysis('http://blahblah...', this). At the moment that is the only place where the address is stored. It cannot be assigned to the boxes value or alt tag as they are already tied up in functions. So is there is a way to effectively launch the onclick event already assigned to each checkbox using .each on all checked checkboxes.

Comment: I would do that by just using IDs for all your boxes and then put all associated data in a js-file, (mapping IDs to whatever data they're manipulating) rather than use alt-tags and other hackish ways of getting it there :) But that would actually be a question on its own in my opinion. Not really the same thing as how to run a function on all checked checkboxes. I'd be glad to help with further examples, but it's a little misplaced.

Comment: OK thanks Jakob Ill give it a try and if all fails you'll see another question up

Answer (score 0):

this is required script

```
$().ready(function(){
    var box, address;
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
           box = this;
           if (box.checked) {
               address = ""; //you can set address either in hidden fields or in metadata
               $('#product_' + box.alt).load(address);
           }
           else {
                $('#product_' + box.alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html');
           }           
           document.getElementById('product_quantity_PRI_' + box.alt).value = box.value;
    });
});
```

Comment: He asked for "all checkboxes that are already ticked on page load to have this function applied to them all". Maybe he didn't mean that, but in any case this code invokes the function for all checkboxes, not just the checked ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class called as "selected" when the check box are checked, you could do something like this

```
$('.selected').function(element){product_analysis(address, element)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how many number of check is checked and then invoke your code.

```
var checkLength = checkObj.length;

for(var i = 0; i < checkLength ; i++) {
 if(radioObj[i].checked) {
 }
// here your code base on check box status
}
```

Comment: You left out the part describing how he would get the checkObj. Also, it's unnecessary to calculate lengths, manually write a for-loop etc. Not a very pretty solution, even if it could get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chaps for all your help here is I I got it. Jakob will probably consider this a hack but it is a data driven site and based on my limited technical knowledge can't be tasked with modifying a JS file every time we add a new product.

```
function product_analysis_global() {

    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    $('#product_' + this.alt).load(this.title);
});
}

function product_analysis(box) {
    if (box.checked) {

    $('#product_' + box.alt).load(box.title);

    }
    else {

    $('#product_' + box.alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html');
    }
    document.getElementById('product_quantity_PRI_' + box.alt).value = box.value;


};
```

Comment: I'll take that comment as a compliment ;) Anyway, I understand that you might not be able to modify any file at any time. However, I suppose that you generate the html-code with all the checkboxes based on the products you have in a database? You should generate the "addresses" variables in my example the same way. Hardcoding it into the JS-file together with all other logic is madness :) so, either you put in a file of its own and let your application generate that file. If you would prefer to generate html only, then you can write it as an inline JavaScript.

Comment: On the other hand, obviously you know the domain better than I do and as long as your solution works, is easy to add new products to and don't cause any issues, then everything is great! Glad to be of help :)

Comment: And by the way, don't miss my last finding. I appended it to my original post!